# Is Cloudmade still updating OSM data downloads?

Tags: openstreetmap, download, cloudmade

I sent this question to Cloudmade but unfortunately they never responded. Hopefully someone here knows something about how they work.

They provide an OSM download for [the Americas](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/americas) which I am using in a project. Although their site states that downloads are updated roughly every month it looks like nothing has changed since December 2011.

Although there are many country and continent-specific downloads available for OSM data online it seems like this is the only place I can get something for all of the Americas.

Any input on Cloudmade's update strategy or alternate sources for Americas data (without setting up my own planet-wide PostGIS) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does not look updated, http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/ has been updated.

Comment: @Mapperz I have previously looked at geofabrik but they break the Americas out into multiple different sections. I'm not sure how successfully I could update my existing americas-only PostGIS database from this source

Comment: Ask Geofabrik. They're helpful people and may consider the request.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst ok I asked GeoFabrik, I will update this post when I know more. I assume that I could load all their separate pieces or North and South America into a single PostGIS db and get the same end result as loading all of the Americas in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did get a response from Cloudmade in the end:

> Our downloads page reports the right date. We will update OSM
>   downloads as soon s possible but for now our developers are busy on
>   the other projects.

This is good news but in my case the uncertainty around update frequency is a problem. I am instead loading the full planet.osm file with a bounding box restriction for the Americas.