# Extract a PostGIS dump from OSM with a particular tag

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osmosis

I'm new to [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org/). I want to extract all restaurants from Switzerland with their capacity if available. I am using [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis). I tried:

```
osmosis --read-pbf file=switzerland.pbf --tf accept-nodes amenity=restaurant --write-xml output.osm
```

(I downloaded switzerland.pbf from http://planet.osm.ch/)

And it looks like it works. I would like to extract it not in XML but as a postgresql/PostGIS format. I tried

```
osmosis --read-pbf file=switzerland.pbf --tf accept-nodes amenity=restaurant --write-pgsql restaurant_osm.psql
```

But it fails with the following error:

```
INFO: Pipeline executing, waiting for completion.
Apr 8, 2014 1:06:08 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.ActiveTaskManager waitForCompletion
SEVERE: Thread for task 1-read-pbf failed
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.)
```

I don't really understand this error. How should I do in order to extract sport facilities, leisure facilities, restaurants and shops from Switzerland version of OSM with their capacity if available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--write-pgsql` wants to talk to a Postgis database. You have not specified any database connection for that task, e.g.:

```
osmosis --read-pbf file=switzerland.pbf --tf accept-nodes shop=supermarket --write-pgsql host=128.178.12.34 database=myDatabase user=myUsername password=myPassword
```

Furthermore, keep in mind that restaurants can also be modelled as closed ways, so you have to look into the way table too.

If you have a postgis database, make sure you have loaded all scripts before populating. My batch reads as follows:

```
%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\createdb -U postgres -E UTF8 -O osmuser osmosisdb
%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\createlang -U postgres plpgsql osmosisdb
%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\psql -U postgres -d osmosisdb -f "%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\share\contrib\postgis-1.5\postgis.sql"
%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\psql -U postgres -d osmosisdb -f "%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\share\contrib\postgis-1.5\spatial_ref_sys.sql"
%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\psql -U postgres -d osmosisdb -f "%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\share\contrib\_int.sql"
%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\psql -U postgres -d osmosisdb -f "%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\share\contrib\hstore.sql"
%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\psql -U postgres -d osmosisdb -f "D:\Karten\OpenStreetMap\osmosis\script\pgsnapshot_schema_0.6.sql"
%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\psql -U postgres -d osmosisdb -f "D:\Karten\OpenStreetMap\osmosis\script\pgsnapshot_schema_0.6_action.sql"
%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\psql -U postgres -d osmosisdb -f "D:\Karten\OpenStreetMap\osmosis\script\pgsnapshot_schema_0.6_bbox.sql"
%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\psql -U postgres -d osmosisdb -f "D:\Karten\OpenStreetMap\osmosis\script\pgsnapshot_schema_0.6_linestring.sql"
```

(and a short version for people with Postgresql 9.x:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
run pgsnapshot_schema_0.6.sql from Osmosis
```

)

And please not that osmosis will give you nodes, ways and relations. If you want a database that can be used for rendering by Mapnik, or to be used with other GIS softawre, osm2pgsql is a better choice. You will get proper polygons out of that.

Alternatively, try to use ogr2ogr for export to other GIS formats.

Comment: It works a bit better, but I get an "ERROR: relation "schema_info" does not exist". Any suggestion? I'm reading some help here: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/20863/osmosis-import-osm-to-postgresql-fails

Comment: I ran pgsnapshot_schema_0.6.sql to build the correct schema. It creates a problem: "ERROR: type "hstore" does not exist".

Comment: You have missed to load the hstore and all scheme sql files in advance, See my extended answer.

Comment: Yes, I just found here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/PostGIS_Setup that the solution is to "CREATE EXTENSION hstore;". Thanks.

Comment: In nowadys, 2018,  osmosis not give geometry?

Answer (score 1):

Try this post: [How to manage the osmosis command line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43239/how-to-manage-the-osmosis-command-line)

Pay attention to comments where I solved some troubles.

Here I have some tricks too: [How to extract primary and secondary roads from OSM data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78791/how-to-extract-primary-and-secondary-roads-from-osm-data)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I need to use first XML output and then use osm2pgsql? It is not possible to directly extract it as pgsql in the way that is described in the detailed usage from osmosis here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage#--write-pgsql_.28--wp.29 ?

Comment: To me it's the easy way since gives me more control. Andre Joost said: `And please not that osmosis will give you nodes, ways and relations. If you want a database that can be used for rendering by Mapnik, or to be used with other GIS softawre, osm2pgsql is a better choice.`. You can connect all commands to make all in one step. I think the XML step will be made in background anyway.